# Transaction doesn't rollback even there was an error?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I created this transaction (my first transaction), there is no row with `Id = 111` in `Teacher` table, however it works on the `Subject` table and inserted a new row. Shouldn't it rollback all the changes?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO Subject (Name, SupervisorId) VALUES('Statistics', 4)
UPDATE Teacher SET Name ='Hady' WHERE Id=111
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I then add some more logic to it, but still not working:

```
Begin Try
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO Subject (Name, SupervisorId) VALUES('Statistics', 4)
UPDATE TeacherO SET Name ='Hady' WHERE Id=111
COMMIT TRANSACTION
End Try
Begin Catch
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
End Catch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you assume, that the attempt to update a row in teacher table when *there is no row with Id = 111 in Teacher table* was an error...

An error occurs, when you do something forbidden or impossible. If you try to add a number to a string without casts. Or if you try to get hands on a not exisiting object. Maybe you want to convert `30.02.2016` to date. All will be an error.

But if you tell the database to update all rows where the id=111, exactly this happens: All rows with id=111 will be updated. The count of affected rows will be zero in your case. But this is not an error...

Comment: I thought of that, so I changed the `Teacher` table to a non-existing one: `TeacherO`, but this doesn't change anything, or that's not the type of error Transaction work on?

Comment: If you try to use `UPDATE` against a table, which does not exist, this should not even compile... **An error was, if you tried to set a *wrong* value to an *existing* row**. Let's assume there is a teacher with Id=2 you would get a **real** error with `UPDATE Teacher SET Id='test' WHERE Id=2;` This should be invalid in any case...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use XACT_ABORT set option to ensure it rolls back. Without it some errors will not cause a roll back.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO Subject (Name, SupervisorId) VALUES('Statistics', 4);
    UPDATE TeacherO SET Name ='Hady' WHERE Id=111;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH
```